# What is a good companion for asparagus?

Tags: companion-planting, asparagus

I am considering planting about 4 asparagus plants in a 5'x7' patch.  The asparagus will take up most of the space in the patch.  What companion plants would work well in such a space?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_companion_plants) recommends: Aster Family flowers, Dill, Coriander, Tomatoes, Parsley, Basil, Comfrey, Marigolds.  Has anybody tried these combinations?

Comment: I planted Tomatoes and Marigolds nearby asparagus 2 years ago.  Our Asparagus patch has been very successful so far.  I haven't tried to plant anything in the Asparagus patch itself though, only nearby.

Answer (score 5):

From [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=what%20is%20a%20good%20companion%20for%20asparagus?&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://organicgardening.about.com/od/vegetablesherbs/p/tomatocompanion.htm&ei=IJp_T-6CCar20gHvtJTVBw&usg=AFQjCNGWHHAc-QRoPFY-JKIGX1xa9bGNig), tomatoes are a logical companion to the asparagus, because the asparagus grows most actively in spring, and the tomatoes fill in later in the season as the asparagus becomes inactive. Also, the tomatoes repel asparagus beetles, which is a great help in summer. It is better to plant the tomatoes on the south side of the asparagus plants, as asparagus gets fairly tall, and will shade the tomatoes if they are on the wrong sides of each other. Marigolds also repel beetles. I personally like tomatoes, because it produces food almost all season.

Answer (score 0):

> What companion plants would work well in such a space?

Something you should try for sure, and not mentioned in your question or existing answer: ***salad***!

What you should avoid as a companion for sure: ***potatoes***!

Comment: I find it curious that that tomatoes are super-good and potatoes are super-bad, and at the same time they come from the same not just family but genus - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanum 

Do you maybe have a source on why potatoes are bad? Would maybe eggplants/aubergenes give beneficial results?